# how to calculate days difference in given two days in php

Tags: php

How do I make a method on how to calculate the number of days between two given days?

For example, I want to know how many days are between Monday and Thursday. 
so I calculated it like this.

Made an array and check the difference of values for Monday and Thursday. which is `1 - 4 = -3`. Ignore the minus symbol, we got `3`. so if we add `3` in current date then obviously we got Thursday date. What I can't able to work is if I got a scenario where I need to calculate the number of days between `Sunday` and `Wednesday`. by applying above technique, we got `7 - 3 = 4` if we add `4` days to current date then we definitely not going to get `Wednesday`. Can anyone help me out of this, please? Not sure need to apply a linked list or what. Need help.

Comment: Your day selection logic is wrong. The difference between days is correct. If your looking for the difference then that is exactly what you get. The reference to 4 is correct, that is the diference between those 2 days. What exactly is what are you trying to acomplish here? Could you be more specific?

Comment: suppose we get 2 inputs in form of string.. 1st is "sunday" and 2nd is "thursday" how do i calculcate number of days between "sunday and "thursday" . if you can provide a function then it would be great. this could work for any input of week days.

Answer (score 1):

If the 1st day is greater than the 2nd day value, you need to offset by 7. Try something like this-

```
function dayDiff($start,$end){
   $weekDays = [
            'Mon' => 1,
            'Tue' => 2,
            'Wed' => 3,
            'Thu' => 4,
            'Fri' => 5,
            'Sat' => 6,
            'Sun' => 7,
    ];
  return ($weekDays[$start] < $weekDays[$end]) ? $weekDays[$end]-$weekDays[$start] : abs($weekDays[$start]-$weekDays[$end]-7);
}
```

this will result in-

```
echo "Mon -> Thu : ".dayDiff("Mon","Thu"); //returns 3
echo "Sun -> Wed : ".dayDiff("Sun","Wed"); //returns 3
echo "Sat -> Wed : ".dayDiff("Sat","Wed"); //returns 4
```

example here - https://3v4l.org/CrYJD

Comment: Thanks for you precious time!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not emotially attached to your array this method using strtotime and date works.
It creates a starting point at the next possible startday (Sunday), and uses that to get the Unix of the next end day(Wednesday).

Then I just subtract start from end and I'm left with how many seconds there is between the two days, divide that by 86400 and we have the number of days between them.

```
$startday ="Sunday";
$endday = "Wednesday";
$start = strtotime("next $startday");
$end = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $start) . " Next $endday");
Echo ($end-$start)/86400;
```

https://3v4l.org/VYjlM

Answer (score -2):

```
function format($a, $b)
{
    if (strtotime($a) > strtotime($b)) list($a, $b) = [$b, $a];
    $start = strtotime($a);
    $stop = strtotime($b);
    $extend = ($stop - $start) / 86400;
    $result['extends'] = $extend;
    if ($extend < 7) {
        $result['daily'] = $extend;
    } elseif ($extend <= 31) {
        if ($stop == strtotime($a . '+1 month')) {
            $result['monthly'] = 1;
        } else {
            $w = floor($extend / 7);
            $d = ($stop - strtotime($a . '+' . $w . ' week')) / 86400;
            $result['weekly'] = $w;
            $result['daily'] = $d;
        }
    } else {
        $y = floor($extend / 365);
        if ($y >= 1) {
            $start = strtotime($a . '+' . $y . 'year');
            $a = date('Y-m-d', $start);
            if ($start > $stop) {
                $a = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($a . '-1 month'));
                $m = 11;
                $y--;
            }
            $extend = ($stop - strtotime($a)) / 86400;
        }
        if (isset($m)) {
            $w = floor($extend / 7);
            $d = $extend - $w * 7;
        } else {
            $m = isset($m) ? $m : round($extend / 30);
            $stop >= strtotime($a . '+' . $m . 'month') ? $m : $m--;
            if ($stop >= strtotime($a . '+' . $m . 'month')) {
                $d = $w = ($stop - strtotime($a . '+' . $m . 'month')) / 86400;
                $w = floor($w / 7);
                $d = $d - $w * 7;
            }
        }
        $result['yearly'] = $y;
        $result['monthly'] = $m;
        $result['weekly'] = $w;
        $result['daily'] = isset($d) ? $d : NULL;
    }

    return array_filter($result);
}
```

Comment: Bro did you even read my question? If yes then please tell me how to use you code to calculate days difference.